# Rewrite SQLite statement SELECT WHERE - Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've written a method that searches the database to find matching lecturers depending on modules. However, when I run this, it saves the same name for all three!

Here is the method:

```
public List<tableModules> getStudentsLecturers(String mod1, String mod2, String mod3) {
        List<tableModules> studentModuleLecturer = new ArrayList<tableModules>();       
        // Select All Query to find lecturers depending on modules      
        Log.d("Lecturers", mod1);
        Log.d("Lecturers", mod2);
        Log.d("Lecturers", mod3);
        String selectQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT " + Module_Lecturer + " FROM " + Table2 + " WHERE " + Module_Name + " = \'" + mod1 + "\' OR \'" + mod2 + "\' OR \'" + mod3 + "\'";
        Log.d("1", "1");
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {               
                tableModules  moduleLecturers = new tableModules();             
                moduleLecturers.modulelecturer = cursor.getString(0);          
                studentModuleLecturer.add(moduleLecturers);         
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return lecture list
        return studentModuleLecturer;       
    }
```

Which is then called here in **MainActivity.java**

```
List<tableModules> lecturers = db.getStudentsLecturers(mod1, mod2, mod3);
                if (!lecturers.isEmpty())
                {           
                for (tableModules session: lecturers)
                {
                    Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    //Save lecturers to list
                    for (int i=0; i < lecturers.size(); i++) {
                        if (counter == 0)
                        {                    
                        lecturer1 = session.modulelecturer.toString();
                        editor.putString("lec1", lecturer1);
                        Log.d("Lecs", "1"); 
                        editor.commit();
                        counter++;
                        }
                        if (counter == 1)
                        {                   
                        lecturer2 = session.modulelecturer.toString();
                        editor.putString("lec2", lecturer2);
                        Log.d("Lecs", "2"); 
                        editor.commit();
                        counter++;
                        }
                        if (counter == 2)
                        {   
                        lecturer3 = session.modulelecturer.toString();
                        editor.putString("lec3", lecturer3);
                        Log.d("Lecs", "3"); 
                        editor.commit();
                        counter++;
                        }
                        else
                        {                               
                            Log.d("Lecs", "ERROR"); 
                        }
                     }
```

I get that I'm saving the same "session.modulelecturer.toString();" to each, but I can't figure out how to alter the SQL method to select all three lecturers for all three seperate modules.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing

```
" WHERE " + Module_Name + " = \'" + mod1 + "\' OR \'" + mod2 + "\' OR \'" + mod3 + "\'";
```

with

```
" WHERE " + Module_Name + " = '" + mod1 + "' OR " + Module_Name + " = '" + mod2 + "' OR " + Module_Name + " = '" + mod3 + "'";
```

In practice, you can't say

```
WHERE ModuleName = 'This' OR 'That'
```

but you can say

```
WHERE ModuleName = 'This' OR ModuleName = 'That'
```

I know it's a drag to rewrite the column name for each possible value, but it's how it works in SQL.

---

Alternatively, you can write a more compact form:

```
WHERE ModuleName IN ('This', 'That', '...')
```

So you query can become:

```
" WHERE " + Module_Name + " IN ('" + mod1 + "', '" + mod2 + "', '" + mod3 + "')";
```

Comment: For some reason this still returns the same names for all three lecturers! :(

Comment: Then you're passing the same values for all the 3 variables. There was an error in your query, whuch jumped to my eyes and I fixed it. Now there's another error, somewhere.